# Inserting rows from df to MS Access Error "number of query values and destination fields are not the same"

Tags: python, sql, pandas, ms-access

I have a dataframe called df2 which has the following columns:

```
IN: df2.columns
Out: 
Index(['Section Names', 'Job Code', 'Job Title', 'Footnotes', 'Rates',
       'Wage Determination', 'Revision Date', 'Revision Number'],
      dtype='object')
```

I count this as 8 columns.

I have saved the column names into cols:

```
IN: cols = "','".join([str(i) for i in df2.columns.tolist()])
IN: print(cols)
OUT: Section Names','Job Code','Job Title','Footnotes','Rates','Wage Determination','Revision Date','Revision Number
```

Again, I'm seeing 8 columns.

And, in Access I have a table that has these columns (none of which are assigned as a primary key, for now):

```
Section Name
Job Code
Job Title
Footnotes 
Rates
Wage Determination
Revision Date
Revision Number
```

which is 8 columns. I tried to execute this code to populate test_table with the data from df2:

```
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    sql = "INSERT INTO `test_table` (`" +cols + "`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
    conn.commit()
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Error: ('21S01', '[21S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same. (-3520) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I was thinking it was because it is trying to insert the index, and did `index_col = 0` when reading the csv file (which assigned to df2). However, that decreased the column count by 1, and I adjusted the cols values and `VALUES` in the sql statement accordingly, but I came up with the same error.

Any ideas?  TIA.

**EDIT** I thought it might be a data types issue. I changed all the data types in Access to 'short text' and the datatype in `df2` to object. Still the same error.

Comment: `Section Names` in the dataframe vs. `Section Name` in the table.  It that difference a problem for Pandas?

Comment: @HansUp, I thought of that also! same error when I changed it to match. I am not thinking it could be different data types between what I have in my df and what is in Access. Going to try changing the data types to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, you need to square bracket or backtick table or column names with spaces and/or special characters. Right now, you use single quotes in your `str.join` but then use backticks in the SQL statement. Simply, use backticks or square brackets in both strings:

```py
# DELIMIT WITH BACK TICKS
cols = "`, `".join(i for i in df2.columns)
qmarks = ", ".join('?' for _ in  df2.columns)

# USING F-STRING
sql = f"INSERT INTO `test_table` (`{cols}`) VALUES ({qmarks})"

for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
    conn.commit()
```

Consider even `executemany`:

```py
cols = "`, `".join(i for i in df2.columns)
qmarks = ", ".join('?' for _ in  df2.columns)
sql = f"INSERT INTO `test_table` (`{cols}`) VALUES ({qmarks})"

vals = df2.to_numpy().tolist()
cursor.executemany(sql, vals)
conn.commit()
```